# When is the ratio of two normals approximately normal?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, approximation, ratio

Suppose that $X \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$ are two independent normal random variables. Define $Z = X/Y$. I noticed that there are some cases where the distribution of $Z$ is close to normal

```
set.seed(11)

X = rnorm(1000,10,1)
Y = rnorm(1000,10,0.1)

Z = X/Y

hist(Y)

shapiro.test(Z)
```

**Questions**. When is the distribution of $Z$ approximately normal? Are there any relevant references to justify this approximation?

Comment: This paper is useful: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00362-012-0429-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page on ratio distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution), in the [section on uncorrelated noncentral normal ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Uncorrelated_noncentral_normal_ratio) says that a normal approximation is possible "under certain conditions".

The reference given is to [Díaz-Francés & Rubio (2013, *Statistical Papers*)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00362-012-0429-2). Somewhat unsurprisingly, the abstract notes that the conditions pertain to the coefficients of variation of the two normals.